# Random Number Generator is repetitive in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

How does one ensure that a model in the form of simulink generated executable "standalone executable" generate different random sequence every time the executable is executed. 
I added `rng('shuffle')` in the initFcn Callbacks, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: What do you use in your model to generate random numbers?

Comment: @Sam try the solution posted, I believe it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found your solution - the rand function always generates the same numbers every time MATLAB is loaded (it gets initialized with a 0 seed).  That's why you get different outputs (re)running from MATLAB than when the exe is built.  The workaround is to add this line to your code (which will instead generate a random seed based on the system clock) ONLY ONCE IN YOUR CODE before your calls to `rand`, `randn`, or `randi`:

```
%THIS IS THE SOLUTION GIVEN FOR AN EXE (UPDATED FOR NEWER MATLAB VERSIONS)
reset(RandStream.getGlobalStream,sum(100*clock))

%OR (THIS IS INSIDE MATLAB, HAVEN'T TRIED WITH AN EXE)
RandStream.setGlobalStream(RandStream('mt19937ar','seed',sum(100*clock))); %note you can use 6 other random number generators, type RandStream.list for more
```

See here for more details: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/104306-why-does-my-compiled-rand-function-give-the-same-values-every-time-i-run-my-matlab-generated-standal

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/336-why-do-i-get-the-same-numbers-in-randn-function?s_tid=answers_rc1-1_p1_Topic

Now if you're using MATLAB coder you're supposed to do something like this (if `clock` isn't available):

```
coder.cinclude('"time.h"')
sd=0;
sd=coder.ceval('time',[]);
rng(sd);
```

All of these solutions work on the `rand`, `randn`, `randi` functions.